# Symantec Backup Exec 11d RALUS Communications Error

Tags: backup, redhat, backupexec, symantec

I'm trying to do a file system backup of a RedHat Enterprise Linux v4 server using Symantec Backup Exec 11d (Rev 7170).  The backup server is Windows Server 2003.

I can browse the target server to create a selection list, and when I do a test run it completes successfully.

However, when I run a real backup, the job fails immediately during the "processing" phase with the error:

*e000fe30 - A communications failure has occured.*

I've tried opening ports (10000, 1025-9999), etc. But no joy.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure sounds like firewall issues. Try stopping iptables, and running again. Also, RALUS can dump a log file - which may give some more to go on.

I use the older UNIX agent myself, which uses port 6101 IIRC - but I believe that the newer client uses tcp/10000 for control and 1024-65535 for transfer.

Last resort is to fire up a network sniffer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the answer, the solution was to open up the tcp ports from 1024-65535.

The iptables looked liked this:

```
[root@MYSERVER ~]# service iptables status  
Table: filter  
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)  
target     prot opt source               destination  
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)  
target     prot opt source               destination  
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination  

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)  
target     prot opt source               destination  
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 255  
ACCEPT     esp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  
ACCEPT     ah   --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251         udp dpt:5353  
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:631  
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:443  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5801  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5802  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5804   
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5901  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5902  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5904  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:9099  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:10000  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:1025  
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

I executed this command to add the new rule:

```
[root@MYSERVER ~]# iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT 14 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
```

Then they looked like this:

```
[root@MYSERVER ~]# service iptables status  
Table: filter  
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)  
target     prot opt source               destination  
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)  
target     prot opt source               destination  
RH-Firewall-1-INPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination  

Chain RH-Firewall-1-INPUT (2 references)  
target     prot opt source               destination  
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           icmp type 255  
ACCEPT     esp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  
ACCEPT     ah   --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251         udp dpt:5353  
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:631  
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:443  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5801  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5802  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5804  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpts:1025:65535  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5901  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5902  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:5904  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:9099  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:10000  
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:1025  
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Save the iptables when you've verified that it works:

```
[root@MYSERVER ~]# service iptables save
```